# Prevent multiple DB requests for the Rails Admin custom field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, rails-admin

I have the custom boolean field in rails admin with nested resource usage

```
class Sector
  has_many :holds, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :sector
  def holden
    holds.find_by_end_date(nil).present?
  end
end
```

When the system renders Sectors list I see the multiple DB requests to get the holden field value for the each Sector.

```
  Hold Load (2.0ms)  SELECT  "holds".* FROM "holds" WHERE "holds"."sector_id" = $1 AND "holds"."end_date" IS NULL LIMIT $2  [["sector_id", 119], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Hold Load (2.0ms)  SELECT  "holds".* FROM "holds" WHERE "holds"."sector_id" = $1 AND "holds"."end_date" IS NULL LIMIT $2  [["sector_id", 118], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Hold Load (4.0ms)  SELECT  "holds".* FROM "holds" WHERE "holds"."sector_id" = $1 AND "holds"."end_date" IS NULL LIMIT $2  [["sector_id", 117], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Hold Load (3.0ms)  SELECT  "holds".* FROM "holds" WHERE "holds"."sector_id" = $1 AND "holds"."end_date" IS NULL LIMIT $2  [["sector_id", 116], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Hold Load (2.0ms)  SELECT  "holds".* FROM "holds" WHERE "holds"."sector_id" = $1 AND "holds"."end_date" IS NULL LIMIT $2  [["sector_id", 115], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Hold Load (3.0ms)  SELECT  "holds".* FROM "holds" WHERE "holds"."sector_id" = $1 AND "holds"."end_date" IS NULL LIMIT $2  [["sector_id", 114], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Hold Load (3.0ms)  SELECT  "holds".* FROM "holds" WHERE "holds"."sector_id" = $1 AND "holds"."end_date" IS NULL LIMIT $2  [["sector_id", 102], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ...
```

How to increase performance for this feature?

Comment: This should help you solve this problem: http://jameshuynh.com/n+1%20problem/rails/2016/03/21/reduce-database-query-in-n-1-problem/